# Digraph vertices: classification by counting outgoing walks

Tags: graphs, finite-automata

I'm reproducing a question I posted on [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2714610/digraph-vertices-classification-by-counting-outgoing-walks) (yet with no answer both there and by myself).

Given a (finite) directed graph $G = (V, E)$. For each vertex $v \in V$ and a natural number $n$, let $W_v(n)$ be the number of walks in $G$ of length exactly $n$ originating at $v$. That is,
$$W_v(0) = 1 \quad\text{and}\quad W_v(n + 1) = \sum_{\substack{u \in V \\ (v, u) \in E}} W_u(n).$$
Now, for $u, v \in V$, let $u \sim v$ iff $W_u(n) = W_v(n)$ for all $n$. This equivalence of vertices induces a partitioning of $V$. What is known on the complexity of computing this partition?

(By "computing", it may have meant an algorithm that assigns each vertex $v\in V$ a number of its class, so that two vertices are equivalent iff they get assigned the same number. I do see some resemblance to the Hopcroft's DFA minimization algorithm, but still the problem being solved is different... and I see this to be a corner case of some harder problems.)

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/97617/755, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2714610/14578.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Comment: Is this partition the same as or coarser than the partition by graph isomorphism? The partition of vertices by graph isomorphism is u∼v iff there exists an isomorphism σ of G such that σ(u)=v. If it is coarser, can you show a simple example?

Comment: @Apass.Jack: It is coarser, of course. Consider $G = (V, E)$ with $V = \{1,2,3\}$ and $E = \{(3, 2)\}$. Then $1 \sim 2$ (with my definition of $\sim$) but there's no automorphism of $G$ taking $1$ to $2$.

Comment: Thanks. I see. How about undirected graph?

Comment: @Apass.Jack: Consider a simple cycle. For each vertex $v$ of it, $W_v(n) = 2^n$. So this time a counterexample is e.g. a graph consisting of two disjoint simple cycles of different lengths.

Comment: @Apass.Jack: There is also a famous [connected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frucht_graph) example.

Comment: Thanks, indeed, Furcht graph has only trivial automorphism but all vertices in the Frucht graph are equivalent. Still in the undirected case. Suppose we define $u\sim_{refined} v$ if there is one-one correspondence $r$ between $u$'s neighbors and $v$'s neighbors such that $u\sim r(u)$. Do you have an example where $u\sim v$ but $u \not\sim_{refined} v$?

Comment: I think it deserves a dedicated question, probably even not on this site. (No, I don't.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $A$ be the adjacency matrix of the graph, let $\mathbf 1$ be the all-ones vector, and let $\delta_v$ be the indicator of vertex $v$. Then
$$
W_v(t) = \delta_v A^t \mathbf 1.
$$
It follows that $v \sim u$ iff for all $t$,
$$
(\delta_u - \delta_v) A^t \mathbf 1 = 0.
$$
Let $n = |V|$. The Cayley–Hamilton theorem shows $A^t$ is always a linear combination of $A^0,\ldots,A^{n-1}$. Therefore
$$
v \sim u \Longleftrightarrow (\delta_u - \delta_v) A^0 \mathbf{1} = \cdots = (\delta_u - \delta_v) A^{n-1} \mathbf{1} = 0.
$$
The latter property can be checked in polynomial time, so the partition can be computed in polynomial time. This procedure can be optimized by computing the kernel of the matrix
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
A^0 \mathbf{1} \\
\cdots \\
A^{n-1} \mathbf{1}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and then finding all $\delta_u-\delta_v$ that belong to it.

Comment: Good. We can take the smallest $n$ such that $\{A^t\mathbf{1} : 0 \leqslant t \leqslant n\}$ is linearly dependent. Close to what I have already, but makes a solid ground under my search of a partition-refinement version of the algorithm. Will probably put the results here as an update.

Thank you very much!